# record data in Odoo?

Tags: python, function, odoo

I tried to create the following function in my Odoo code :

```
def _pourcentage(self,cr,uid,ids,fields,arg,context=None):
    x={}
    for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids):
            x[record.id]=len(record.attendee_ids/self.nb_places)*100
    return x
```

and i get this error (AttributeError: 'openacademy.session' object has no attribute '_ids') when i try to acess a session.

attendee_ids is in a relation one2many with session.

can anyone help , thanks.

Comment: Put your whole code of Class with fields definition

Comment: Rutul Raval , thank you for your interest , the problem was in fact very simple , i should have added spaces , so that the server does not interpret the whole expression as one single string.